# An event when document stops loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have a web page whose large parts are constructed on the front-end, in JavaScript. When the basic HTML is parsed and the DOM tree is constructed, the "ready" event triggers. At this event, a JavaScript code launches that continues with the construction of the web page.

```
$().ready(function() {
    $(document.body).html('<img src = "img.png" />');
    $.ajax({
        url: 'text.txt'
    });
});
```

As you can see in this tiny example,

- new elements are added to DOM
- more stuff, like images is being loaded
- ajax requests are being sent

Only when all of this finishes, when the browser's loading progress bar disappears for the first time, I consider my document to be actually ready. Is there a reasonable way to handle this event?

Note that this:

```
$().ready(function() {
    $(document.body).html('<img src = "img.png" />');
    $.ajax({
        url: 'text.txt'
    });
    alert('Document constructed!');
});
```

does not suffice, as HTTP requests are asynchronous. Maybe attaching handlers to every single request and then checking if all have finished is one way to do what I want, but I'm looking for something more elegant.

**Appendix:**
A more formal definition of the event I'm looking for:

The event when both the document is ready and the page's dynamic content finishes loading / executing for the first time, unless the user triggers another events with mouse moving, clicking etc.

Comment: How does the browser know that you're done calling AJAX and what not?  It doesn't!  This is something you have to handle within your application.

Comment: Well, the browser definitely knows when the dynamic content stops executing for the first time, as the progressbar disappears then. But note, that I don't expect the browser to expose such an event in API. But I'm looking for an elegant application solution, if someone has heard of such.

Comment: Well, I have to remove my answer, since now I completely stopped understanding what you want.

Comment: P.S. Don't use `$().ready(function(){`, use `$(document).ready(function(){` or better yet `$(function(){`  http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: @Rocket Ah, thx. The `ready` event apparently isn't tied to any actual element, so I thought there is no reason to put one there :) Didn't know it's not recommended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described [here](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/), you can sign up for load events for individual images when they finally load. However, as also described there, that may not be reliable across browsers or if the image is already in the browser's cache. So I think at least part of that is not 100% trustworthy. With that said, you can easily hook to a bunch of different asynchronous events and then only react when all of them have completed. For example:

```
$(document.body).html('<img src="img.png" id="porcupine"/>');

var ajaxPromise1 = $.get(...);
var ajaxPromise2 = $.get(...);
var imgLoadDeferred1 = $.Deferred();

$("#porcupine").load(
  function() {
    imgLoadDeferred1.resolve();
  }
);

$.when(ajaxPromise1, ajaxPromise2, imgLoadDeferred1).done(
  function () {
    console.log("Everything's done.");
  }
);
```

If you want to allow for the fact that the image load may never generate an event, you could also set a timer which would go off eventually and try to resolve the imgLoadDeferred1 if it is not already resolved. That way you don't get stuck waiting for an event that never happens.

Comment: `load` may not be absolutely trustworthy, but cross-browser things like this seldom are. Anyway, your code seems to solve my problem. Thanks for a complete answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `.ajaxStop()`.

Used like so:

```
$("#loading").ajaxStop(function(){
      $(this).hide();
});
```

It does't really matter what DOM element you attach to unless you want to use `this` as is done in the above example.

Source: http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/

Comment: So jQuery has basically implemented that outgoing requests counter. But does this apply to only AJAX requests made by `jQuery` ? I am using more frameworks in my code. Furthermore, this still doesn't cover the requests for images. But thx for the information, +1.

Comment: This **does** apply to *only* AJAX requests made by jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Add global counter to ajax calls in way that when ajax request is ready it calls `addToReadyCounter();` function that will +1 to glogal `var readyCount;`.

Within same function check your readyCount and trigger event handler

```
var readyCount = 0, ajaxRequestCount = 5;
function addToReadyCount() {
    ++readyCount;
    if (readyCount >= ajaxRequestCount) {
        documentReadyEvent();
    }
}

$.ajax(
...
    success: function(data){
        addToReadyCount();
}
...);
```

If you are only using `success: ...` for addToReaadyCount documentReadyEvent() only triggers if all call succeed, use other .ajax() event handlers to increment counter in case of error.

Comment: Thank you, but I actually described this solution in my question as not elegant enough for what I want. Besides, this still doesn't take those images into account.

Comment: @Imp for images (and all other resources) add `$(window).load(function(){addToReadyCount();});`

Comment: Thx. According to `jQuery` specification, it is not much reliable, but yes, it helps.